# HTML/JS QR Decoder

Tags: javascript, html, qr-code

I've been trying to program a QR code decoder in HTML and JavaScript that does not need a webcam or scannner. You just click on some buttons (625 times to fill the 25x25 code) to enter the QR code. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>QR Hacker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Note that this only supports 25x25 QR Codes. May take few clicks to fill certain squares.
    Skipped boxes are colored red. All 625 squares should end up being black and/or red before decoding.</p>
    <canvas id="canv" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
    <script>
        var i;
        var a = document.getElementById("canv");
        var b = a.getContext("2d");
        b.translate(0.5,0.5);
        b.lineWidth = 1;
        //////////GRID SETUP//////////
        for (var y = 0; y <= 200; y += 8) {
            strokeLine(b, y);
        }

        function strokeLine(ctx, y) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(0, y);
            ctx.lineTo(300, y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        for (var x = 0; x <= 200; x += 8) {
            strokxLine(b, x);
        }

        function strokxLine(ctx, x) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(x, 300);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        /////////////DRAW//////////////
        var r = 0;
        var s = 0;
        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;
        function createArray(length) {
            var arr = new Array(length || 0),
            i = length;
            if (arguments.length > 1) {
                var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
                while(i--) arr[length-1 - i] = createArray.apply(this, args);
            }

            return arr;
        }
        var data = createArray(25,25);
        function fill(d,e)
        {
            if(d<208)
            {
                b.fillRect(d,e,8,8);
                r += 8;
            }
            if(r>200)
            {
                d = 0;
                e += 8;
                r = 0;
                s += 8;
            }
        };
        function skip()
        {
            b.fillStyle="rgb(255,0,0)";
            fill(r,s);
            b.fillStyle="#000000";
        };
    </script>
    <button type="button" onclick="fill(r,s);">Fill in next square</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="skip();">Skip next square</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="decode();">Decode!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

So what I want to do now is to make a function `decode()` that reads the colors on screen and dumps some binary data into an array (black squares = 1, red squares = 0). It would be dumped into an array of size 25*25. I've tried using the `getImageData()` method on `b=a.getContext()` but I couldn't figure out how to calculate the x and y coordinates in range (0,25) from the byte of pixel color being read from a for loop. Please help! ;-;

Comment: *"You just click on some buttons (625 times..."* - I'm not sure that "just" is quite the right word there - maybe "laboriously" would be more appropriate...

Comment: OK, so you've written the easy part. `decode` needs to do more than just read the "pixels", where's the part of the code that actually decodes the pixel data to the text value of the QRcode? Is that going to be the next question?

Comment: @nnnnnn - it wouldn't be 625 times for 25x25 ... because that would be all black!! Looking at most QR codes, it'd be *only* 300 to 400 clicks - not so bad now, is it? :p

Comment: Oh no. I just want to know how to read the binary data. I got the actual 'translating' part in my brain. Also, yes it would be all 625 clicks because in my code you have to also click on 'skip next square' to encode a 0.

Comment: Seeing as you're using buttons to fill/skip ... just record (in an array, string, whatever) the order in which the buttons are clicked - no need to "scan" the resulting image at all

Comment: ok thanks. I'll try that out.